# PostgreSQL use NULL column or empty - effect on index

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a table for my users. username is `NULL` by default ... also user first name and last name but i have 2 implementions of my users table and i want to know which one is better... i must use `NULL` for these columns (username, first_name, last_name, ...) or all columns be `NOT NULL`
and just use `''` for those empty columns ? I want to know that using `NULL` is better or keep the tables `NOT NULL` and just use empty string `''` ?

Also for indexing, which one is better ?

**Way 1 (All `NOT NULL` with empty string)**

```
CREATE TABLE "user"(
  "id" serial NOT NULL,
  "username" character varying(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  "first_name" character varying(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  "last_name" character varying(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
);

CREATE INDEX "user_username_idx"
    ON "username" USING hash ("username")
    WHERE "username" <> '';

CREATE INDEX "user_first_name_idx"
    ON "first_name" USING gin ("first_name" gin_trgm_ops)
    WHERE "first_name" <> '';

CREATE INDEX "user_last_name_idx"
    ON "last_name" USING gin ("last_name" gin_trgm_ops)
    WHERE "last_name" <> '';
```

**Way 2 (Using `NULL`)**

```
CREATE TABLE "user"(
  "id" serial NOT NULL,
  "username" character varying(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  "first_name" character varying(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  "last_name" character varying(32) DEFAULT NULL,
);

CREATE INDEX "user_username_idx"
    ON "username" USING hash ("username");

CREATE INDEX "user_first_name_idx"
    ON "first_name" USING gin ("first_name" gin_trgm_ops);

CREATE INDEX "user_last_name_idx"
    ON "last_name" USING gin ("last_name" gin_trgm_ops);
```

Which way is better for both storage usage or index performance and ... ??

Comment: Option #2 hands down.

Comment: With option 2 I would add `where ... is not null` to the index definitions

Comment: I think both are bad. Don't store garbage data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe we will be happy to hear your real method !!! because there isn't another way except to store the first-name and ... in another table which is very bad ... When we have no data, there is no garbage !!!

Comment: Sorry if I sounded dismissive. But is it useful to have a user who has no user name or personal name? I think that these attributes should be `NOT NULL`. To make up for my unhelpful comment, [here](https://thebuild.com/presentations/no-pk-pgconf-eu-2017.pdf) are slides from a great talk I saw on how to model names in a database. I agree that of the alternatives presented, #2 is better.

Answer (score 0):

Performance and storage wise it won't matter much.

Usually null is used when there is no data available and an empty string is used when there is data, but it is just empty.

If you want to be efficient on storage and performance it would be worthwhile to have a look at your indexes, because those also come with drawbacks:

1. An index costs disk space.
2. An index needs to be updated each time you write something to this table.
3. An index is basically a copy of your data.

I would advise to only add an index on a column if you really need it.

Comment: So you choosing option #2?

Comment: Yes, in this case i would.